# Spring Suspended Transaction keep connection?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

Hello I have question regarding connection blocks. Following is my method calls.

1. Client -> Method A [@Transactional(readOnly = true)]
   -----  Transaction 1 created
2. Method A -> Method B [@Transactional(readOnly = false)]
   -----  Transaction 1 suspended, Transaction 2 created
3. Method B -> DB updates -> Back to method A
   -----  Transaction 2 committed, Transaction 1 resumed

Now my question is what really happened with connection used by read transaction (method A) when new transaction started (method B) ??
From what I can see in session manager, Method A's transaction kept on hold (DOES NOT RELEASED) until method B completed. Is it true?

Does spring suspended transaction keep hold the connection until it nested transaction does not finish?

Comment: There is no suspention, Method B just participates in the already existing transaction of Method A, unless it is marked with `REQUIRES_NEW`. But if there are 2 transactions they both hold a connection.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mentioned: REQUIRES_NEW. Method B is new transaction. So even if Method A's transaction is read only and suspended it hold the connection right?

Comment: Yes, each transaction has its own connection.